# Representing UUID struct as char uuid[128]

Tags: c, char, byte, uuid

If I have the following UUID struct:

```
typedef unsigned long   unsigned32;
typedef unsigned short  unsigned16;
typedef unsigned char   unsigned8;
typedef unsigned char   byte;

typedef struct {
    unsigned32  time_low;
    unsigned16  time_mid;
    unsigned16  time_hi_and_version;
    unsigned8   clock_seq_hi_and_reserved;
    unsigned8   clock_seq_low;
    byte        node[6];
} uuid_t;
```

Would it be possible to represent it as a char? Such as:

```
unsigned char uuid[128];
```

And if that was the case, how would I manipulate values like:

```
uuid.time_low = htonl(uuid.time_low);                       //uuid[0...32]  = htonl(uuid[0...32])?
uuid.time_mid = htons(uuid.time_mid);                       //uuid[33...48] = htonl(uuid[33...48])?
uuid.time_hi_and_version = htons(uuid.time_hi_and_version); //uuid[49...64] = htonl(uuid[49...64])?
```

So my question is, how would I actually implement the below example in real code:

```
uuid[0...32]  = htonl(uuid[0...32])
```

Am I on the right track? Any suggestions are really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, For doing that serialization, your structure should be packed.

You can do that by using some preprocessor directive like `__attribute((packed))`, but that is compiler specific and your code will not be portable.

Once you are sure that your structure is packed, you can use a `union` for interchanging the structure and char array.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean